# What is wrong in the following Lambda code that throws up module error?

Tags: json, aws-lambda, xmlhttprequest

Using the following code to use make an API that connects to Amazon AWS. This is the AMazon Lambda code that I use-

import boto3
    import json
    import requests
    from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

```
region = 'us-east-1' 
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, 
service, session_token=credentials.token)

host = 'XXX.com'
index = 'items'
url = 'https://' + host + '/' + index + '/_search'

# Lambda execution starts here
def handler(event, context):

# Put the user query into the query DSL for more accurate search results.
# Note that certain fields are boosted (^).
query = {
    "query": {
    "multi_match": {
            "query": event['queryStringParameters']['q'],
            }
    }
}

# ES 6.x requires an explicit Content-Type header
headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

# Make the signed HTTP request
r = requests.get(url, auth=awsauth, headers=headers, 
data=json.dumps(query))

# Create the response and add some extra content to support CORS
response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
    },
    "isBase64Encoded": False
}

# Add the search results to the response
response['body'] = r.text
return response
```

This should connect to an AWS ES cluster with endpoint XXX.com

Getting output when trying to test -

```
START RequestId: f640016e-e4d6-469f-b74d-838b9402968b Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
END RequestId: f640016e-e4d6-469f-b74d-838b9402968b
REPORT RequestId: f640016e-e4d6-469f-b74d-838b9402968b  Duration: 
44.49 ms    Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max 
Memory Used: 58 MB
```

Comment: that means your handler function has syntax errors. check if your indentation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a Lambda function, we need to specify a [handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html), which is a function in your code, that the AWS Lambda service can invoke when the given Lambda function is executed.

By default, a Python Lambda function is created with handler as `lambda_function.lambda_handler` which signifies that the service must invoke `lambda_handler` function contained inside `lambda_function` module.

From the error you're receiving, it seems that the `handler` is incorrectly configured to something like `index.<something>`, and since there's no Python module called `index` in your deployment package, Lambda is unable to import the same in order to start the execution.

Answer (score 0):

- If i am getting things correctly to connect to a AWS ES cluster you need something of this sort

```
import gitlab
import logging
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import boto3
#from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
ES_HOST = {'host':'search-testelasticsearch-xxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-2.es.amazonaws.com', 'port': 443}


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    LOGGER.info('started')
    dump2={
        'number': 9
    }

    service = 'es'
    credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
    print('-------------------------------------------')
    print(credentials.access_key)
    print(credentials.secret_key)
    print('--------------------------------------------------------')
    awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, "eu-west-2", service, session_token=credentials.token)
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[ES_HOST], http_auth = awsauth, use_ssl = True, verify_certs = True, connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection)
    DAVID_INDEX = 'test_index'
    response = es.index(index=DAVID_INDEX, doc_type='is_this_important?', body=dump2, id='4')
```